# Can't seem to authenticate a request to my ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, restsharp

I have a local API I am running for my project where I hacked together a method to grab profile data of a currently signed in user like so:

```
[HttpGet("profile"), Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetProfile()
{
    var claim = HttpContext.User.Claims.First(o => o.Type == "id");
    var usr = _userVerification.GetUser(int.Parse(claim.Value));
    return new OkObjectResult(new GenericAPIResponse<ProfileVM>(new ProfileVM()
    {
        FirstName = usr.FirstName,
        Id = usr.UserId,
        LastName = usr.LastName,
        Role = (ProfileVM.RoleType)usr.Role
    }));
}
```

In the API project I have configured a JWT auth and am passing a token through the `Authorization` header to "sign in". When I do it manually through fiddler everything works fine, but whenever I try calling it from the client app it just never wants to put that header in the request for some unknown reason.

In my client I finally settled for this kind of approach with RestSharp:

```
if (bearer != null)
    client.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(bearer);
...
public async Task<GenericAPIResponse<ProfileVM>> GetUserProfile()
{
    var req = new RestRequest("/user/profile");
    //req.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {bearer}"); <- tried that as well but no luck
    var res = await client.ExecuteAsync(req);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GenericAPIResponse<ProfileVM>>(res.Content);        
}
```

Now the problem is I always keep getting a 401 error because the AUTHORIZATION header never gets included in the request. I tired with Refit earlier as well by making a method declaration as such:

```
Task<GenericAPIResponse<ProfileVM>> GetProfile([Header("Authorization")] string token);
```

Nothing. It just seems like I can't add an authorization header to my requests no matter what I do, while adding any other `X-` header with Refit works just fine.

Here's what the above code with RestSharp results in (copied from Fiddler4):

```
GET https://localhost:44355/api/user/profile HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44355
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/106.15.0.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

I am officially out of ideas and starting to go in circles. What am I missing here? Can I get some fresh perspective here please?

Comment: Have you configured the authentication service? If it's missing then that might cause it to skip the header.

Comment: Yes I have, unless I missed something essential but I don't think so, since when manually sending the request the auth works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A `RestRequest` is just an `HttpRequest` with a fancy coat of paint, so I always add a bearer token header like this, by adding it to a `HttpRequestMessage` object which I hand off to an `HttpClient` to process for me.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, myFullUrl);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

var response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

### Update

To do this using RestSharp's native functionality, you'd do this.

```
client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", bearerToken));
```

The idea is that you authenticate the `RestClient` itself, instead of adding the authentication to each Rest request.